# How to join two tables with same primary key name but different values

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-relationship

I learnt today about "exclusive entities". I have following ER diagram:

[image]

With 2 exclusive entities. When I do a physical data model via power designers creation tool it resolves to

[image]

Now I want to join both in one table and display the id and room_name

The structure I want to get is:

```
room_id | room_name
```

The room_id's in room and bedroom are different. bedroom has for example the ids 1-10 and kitchen the ids from 11-20.

I have the feeling that I might have a bad design, because the joins I tried don't get me the desired result.

My best guess is to use a natural join like*

```
SELECT room_id, room_name 
FROM bedroom 
NATURAL JOIN kitchen;
```

This returns the correct format but the results are empty.

Furthermore I'm looking to get a table in the format:

```
room_id | roon_name | bedCount | chairCount
```

Comment: Start with `room` as the driving table, left join `bedroom` left join `kitchen`

Comment: Since you don't have  columns with common value in both the tables then you cannot join. Did you try this as there are no join columns it will give a Cartesian, (query is untested) SELECT DISTINCT BR.room_id, BR.room_name, KT.chairCount, KT.room_name from bedroom BR, kitchen KT

Comment: @Charlieface the table room doesnt exist in my tables. I only have the resulting tables bedrrom and kitchen

Comment: That is where you are going wrong. You should have a `Room` table, PK is two columns: `(Id, Type)` Then these two tables should each have a column `RoomType`, but `CHECK` constrained to a single value per table (say 1 and 2), the PK is also `(ID, Type)` and FK on `Room` same columns. This is an optional relationship, or in OOP a derived class would be modeled like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you requested with a full outer join:

```
select room_id, room_name, b.bedcount, k.chaircount
from   bedroom b full outer join kitchen k using (room_id, room_name)
;
```

This is almost equivalent to the query you attempted - but you need a `natural FULL OUTER join` rather than the (inner) `natural join` you tried. Note, however, that many (most?) practitioners view the `natural join` syntax with suspicion, for various reasons; the `using` clause as I demonstrated above seems to be accepted more easily. (Of course, even with a natural join, you might be best served still naming specifically the columns you want in the output.)

Although the more common approach for cases like this is a straightforward `union all`:

```
select room_id, room_name, bedcount, cast (null as number) as chaircount
from   bedroom
UNION ALL
select room_id, room_name, null    , chaircount
from   kitchen
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can union the two tables together such as:

```
select room_id, room_name
from bedroom
union 
select room_id,room_name
from kitchen
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I add them if I want also to display bed and charCount?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join them as you have nothing in common between the tables upon which to join the tables. What you need to do is give the tables a common column that they can join upon; such as a room will be in a building so create a `buildings` table and then each of the `rooms` should contain a foreign key to the containing building.

I.e.

```sql
CREATE TABLE buildings (
  id   INT
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT buildings__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(20)
       NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
  id          INT
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              CONSTRAINT rooms__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  building_id INT
              NOT NULL
              CONSTRAINT rooms__building_id__fk REFERENCES buildings (id),
  room_name   VARCHAR2(20)
              NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT rooms__id__rn__u UNIQUE ( id, room_name )
);

CREATE TABLE kitchens (
  id          INT
              CONSTRAINT kitchens__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  room_name   VARCHAR2(20)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 'kitchen' )
              NOT NULL,
  chairCount  INT,
  CONSTRAINT kitchens__id__rn__fk
    FOREIGN KEY ( id, room_name ) REFERENCES rooms ( id, room_name )
);

CREATE TABLE bedrooms (
  id          INT
              CONSTRAINT bedrooms__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  room_name   VARCHAR2(20)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 'bedroom' )
              NOT NULL,
  bedCount    INT,
  CONSTRAINT bedrooms__id__rn__fk
    FOREIGN KEY ( id, room_name ) REFERENCES rooms ( id, room_name )
);
```

Then, if you:

```sql
INSERT INTO buildings ( id, name ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, 'Building1' );
INSERT INTO rooms ( id, building_id, room_name ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, 1, 'kitchen' );
INSERT INTO rooms ( id, building_id, room_name ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, 1, 'bedroom' );
INSERT INTO kitchens ( id, chairCount ) VALUES ( 1, 42 );
INSERT INTO bedrooms ( id, bedCount ) VALUES ( 2, 13 );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT b.id AS building_id,
       b.name AS building_name,
       rk.id AS kitchen_id,
       k.chairCount,
       rb.id AS bedroom_id,
       br.bedCount
FROM   buildings b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN rooms rk
       ON ( b.id = rk.building_id AND rk.room_name = 'kitchen' )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN kitchens k
       ON ( rk.id = k.id AND rk.room_name = k.room_name )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN rooms rb
       ON ( b.id = rb.building_id AND rb.room_name = 'bedroom' )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN bedrooms br
       ON ( rb.id = br.id AND rb.room_name = br.room_name )
```

Outputs:

> ```
> BUILDING_ID | BUILDING_NAME | KITCHEN_ID | CHAIRCOUNT | BEDROOM_ID | BEDCOUNT
> ----------: | :------------ | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | -------:
>           1 | Building1     |          1 |         42 |          2 |       13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32f42bdd6937a059ca617454f32cce1f)*

Comment: "You cannot join them as they have nothing in common" is incorrect. They have the PK column in common, just the values are disjoint. A `union all` of just the PK's is the same as a "full outer join" on the PK column.